# Goal not firing

Tags: personalization, goals

I am attempting to setup a goal where if a user in a single visit, visits certain 2 to 3 pages than on landing pages they will see unique content.

I don't want to repeat the rule on each landing page of if they view those three pages so a Goal seems like the best option so that I can just say if they triggered this goal on this visit show this content on each page it will affect.

However the goal isn't firing so I tried to go simple first and set it up if they visit one page:

I setup a basic goal of if a user visits a specific page.
Then on a second page set a component to display different content if the basic goal was completed.

However the goal isn't firing, I've made sure the goal is deployed and published as well as the page with the component, does not display goal has fired in analytics.

I then altered the goal and set it to isGoal I apply that to any page that has nothing to do with the goal and the goal registers in analytics and displays the unique content on the page.

So assigning a goal on the page like that won't work for when I want them to visit more than one page as it is considered complete if they visit the page that has the goal on it whether goal rules were met or not.

An help would be greatly appreciated I'm on Sitecore 10.

[image: Goal Setup]

[image: Goal setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your user case, you need to configure the goal as a live event:

[image]

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-platform/en/live-event-detection.html